# Salesforce Duplicate Management - Importing Duplicates

Tags: data-loader, import, duplicate-management

I have Duplicate management implemented in our org. We do a fuzzy match on account names, but allow users to save if there is a possible duplicate.

I have just imported a number of account, of which I know they are not duplicates, however there are accounts in salesforce that have a similar name, so are caught by the duplicate rule. Is there a way of getting round the matching rule when I import these accounts, or should I just disable it during import?

We always do imports with a specific user, so maybe there is something I can change in the profile?

Answer (score 0):

During the import you can set the check box Allow Duplicate field on the record so it will bypass the check.

Answer (score 0):

**Duplicate Rules** have a section called **Conditions** that allow to specify logic that determines when the rule should be invoked (see attached screenshot).

So for example you could add a condition to exclude that user explicitly.  Or you could write a condition to exclude all users with a Sys Admin profile.  Or, like Travis mentioned above, you could even drive the logic based on custom checkbox on the record.

[image]